# C#/SQL Reusing parameter for list of values

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlcommand

How do I generate SqlCommand for list of parameters?
How to properly reuse same parameter with new OR clause?

```
public class InputList
{
    public string col1 { get; set; }
    public string col2 { get; set; }
}

public void Exec(IList<InputList> list)
{
   try
   {
       using (var conn = new SqlConnection(Settings.Default.DBConnStr))
       using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
       {
           conn.Open();
           cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

           // want to use SqlParameter to prevent sql injection
           var clause = list
                           .Select(x => $"(col1 = {x.col1} AND col2 = {x.col2}) OR ")
                           .Aggregate((curr, next) => curr + " " + next);
           // TODO: remove trainling OR

           cmd.CommandText =
               $@"SELECT *
                  FROM T
                  WHERE {clause}";

           // TODO: execute reader
        }
   }
   catch()
}
```

I have to iterate list of objects to compile WHERE clause

```
SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE
(col1 = @col1 AND col2 = @col2) OR
(col1 = @col1 AND col2 = @col2) OR
...
(col1 = @col1 AND col2 = @col2)
```

Comment: Could you, please, *elaborate* the question? What is *list of parameters* in your case? Which *columns* are involved in filtering (the query in the question doesn't have a good filter) etc.

Comment: For more than a few values, you're generally better off sticking your data in a table-valued parameter, which avoids dynamic SQL altogether.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, thanks, I'll stick to that option

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find solution for my initial request, but table-valued parameters (TVP) works well for my case.
Thanks to @JeroenMostert for reminding about TVP

I had to rework my query and move clauses from WHERE into INNER JOIN section
`SELECT * 
 FROM T
 INNER JOIN @TVP TVP
 ON  TVP.col1 = T.col1 
 AND TVP.col2 = T.col2`

This won't work if you aren't allowed to create TVP in database